# Custom TypeScriptWorker size

Tags: file, size

I built a custom TypeScriptWorker for my project. It is working perfectly.
However, the compiled size is over 44MB from webpack.
I am wondering if this is expected behavior or there are some ways to reduce the size?

Thanks